OpenSearch shards showing 0 but get hits still
My goal is to search for images (that are converted into MobileNet vectors) to find the most with the most similarity (kNN).
I am using the OpenSearch dashboard to run my queries.
I created my vector database, populated with a few vectors, and then started to work on my queries to search and to get the comparisons.
I discovered that my hits were correct, but in response the key, _shards, it's properties were zero. I should be expecting:
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },

Instead I got
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },

I found it weird, and I want to get to the bottom of it, because I want my responses to be as accurate as possible.
My initial query to create my index:
PUT /example1
{
    "settings": {
    "index": {
      "knn": true,
      "knn.algo_param.ef_search": 100,
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "knn_vector",
        "dimension": 1024,
        "method": {
          "name": "hnsw",
          "space_type": "l2",
          "engine": "nmslib",
          "parameters": {
            "ef_construction": 100,
            "m": 16
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "model": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

My search query:
POST /example1/_search
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "knn": {
      "location": {
        "vector": [ … ],
        "k": 3
      }
    }
  }
}

My query response:
{
  "took": 13,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "example1",
        "_id": "1%3A0%3AXi2quJEBIXYW0IdbZ5M7",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "location": […],
          "title": "hit2",
          "model": "whatever"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "example1",
        "_id": "1%3A0%3AIACYn5EBre0qXCPenjLi",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "location": […],
          "title": "hit0",
          "model": "whatever"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "example1",
        "_id": "1%3A0%3AXS2quJEBIXYW0IdbB5P5",
        "_score": 0.25,
        "_source": {
          "location": […],
          "title": "hit0",
          "model": "whatever"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I've tried re-creating the index several times, but I continue get the same result.
I checked of the status of my indices by running:
GET /_cluster/health
health status index    uuid                 pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
              example1 HUWYn5EBowClHUzpGIM4                  4            0     99.8kb         99.8kb
              example0 5rXimpEB2nPz6xarjyts                 11            0    252.6kb        252.6kb

